# Сортировка multiset

Tags: c++, сортировка, multiset

Есть `multiset<multiset<int>> cnt;`
Хочу отсортировать cnt по последнему элементу multiset-ов.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно передать `std::multiset` собственную операцию сравнения. Сравнение должно быть [строгим слабым](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). Или по-простому - операция "меньше". Это должно быть нечто, что можно вызвать как функцию с двумя аргументами, и получить `bool` на выходе. Агрументы должны быть того типа, который храниться в контейнере - в вашем случае `std::multiset<int>`

Я, для таких целей, предпочитаю использовать структуру с оператором `()`. Но вы можете использовать функцию или лямбду.

```
struct LastElementLess{
    bool operator()(const std::multiset<int> &first, const std::multiset<int> &second) const{
        if(second.empty()){
            return false;
        }

        if(first.empty()){
            return true;
        }

        return *first.rbegin() < *second.rbegin();
    }
};

//...   

std::multiset<std::multiset<int>, LastElementLess> ssi
```

[Пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b1c266711c2e606)